# Copy scripts in MPC (Makefile, Project, and Workspace Creator)

Tags: makefile

In maintaining a project built with [MPC (Makefile, Project, and Workspace Creator)](http://downloads.ociweb.com/MPC/docs/html/MakeProjectCreator.html), I'd like to add a recipe to simply copy some scripts from one location to another.

If I were writing the makefile directly it would be easy: just add another line to the appropriate recipe.  But I don't know how to do it with MPC.

I've tried variations of this code, but it creates a skeleton makefile which does nothing.

```
project(jsonscripts) : ecp {

    Define_Custom(PHP) {
        command     = cp <%input%> scripts/
    }

    PHP_Files {
        *.php
    }

    Source_Files {
    }
}
```

- Deleting the `Source_Files` or putting the php files into `Source_Files` creates a Makefile which tries to compile
  the *.php files with gcc.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I could find no way to elegantly make it work.  In the end, I added a `postbuild` command like this:

```
project(json) : ecp {     

    sharedname = someLibname

    libpaths += $(LIBDIR) 
    libs     += alib blib

    Source_Files {
        aa.cpp
        bb.cpp
        cc.cpp
    }

    postbuild = \
      mkdir -p $(PROJHOME)/bin/util ; \
      cp -v scriptA.php scriptB.php $(BIN)/util/ ; \
      echo Scripts Copied to $(BIN)/util
}
```